# what is the difference between regex vs split(at least in my case)?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
\\ regex command
console.log(str.match(/\n/).length);

\\split() method
console.log(str.split("\n").length - 1);
```

I will like to know why the regex code does not match as compared with the split() method. A brief background of my coding exercise: I am tasked to find the number of newlines in the string variable `str`.

Comment: When you say "does not work," do you mean the results don't match? What inputs are you using for `str` that produce this problem?

Comment: `str.match(/\n/).length` will always be at most `1`. Use `/\n/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a global flag at the end of the regex like so - `/\n/g`. This makes it match all occurances of your pattern instead of just the first one.